# External CSS stylesheet working only in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, css

(Sorry for my bad grammar, English is not my native)

I started to refresh my knowledge about HTML5 and CSS.

Started with basics.

Made html file and CSS stylesheet in folder in my PC.
Wrote some HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://www.google.lv/"><button>Ej uz Google!</button></a>


</body>
</html>
```

And CSS stylesheet :

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/sunset_horizon_above_clouds_4k-1366x768.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
button{
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
button:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

But all is Ok when i open my HTML locally in Dreamweaver.
When i open it locally in any of my browsers, it shows only simple button and nothing from CSS stylesheet :(

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Have a nice day!

Comment: You're using a relative path in your `<link href="#">` so pages in subdrectories will look for the stylesheet in the same directory when it isn't there. Use a forward-slash to make it absolute: `/styles.css`.

Comment: Open Developer tools in browser and check if all your links are loaded or not. Or view-source of the page and click the styles.css to check if it is getting loaded or not.

Comment: I just used your code in Codepen,and every thing is working fine, CSS loads fine. Please hit the below link. https://codepen.io/pen/`enter code here` I wonder how come it cannot open in other browsers. Please check the relative path of your CSS link in your project. Thanks.

Comment: This question should be closed because the problem is caused by a typo. The media type of CSS is `text/css` not `style/css`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry if my question was dumb, and thanks for helping.

I just made some changes by help of mighty Google and comments from this question :)

So i changed something in HEAD section :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Seda Mājaslapa</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("styles.css");
    </style>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/jacket.png">
</head>
```

Thanks for helping!
I'm sorry if my question wasn't good. I'm just refreshing my knowledge in HTML5 and CSS  :)

Have a nice day!

P.S. Where is some good HTML5 and CSS tutorials (i know w3schools already ) :)

Comment: @Turnip But it's working with these changes fine, and everywhere :)

Comment: Inline style that only imports a CSS file is just silly. The original code would have also worked just fine by fixing the type, and it wouldn't have been this kind of Rube Goldberg monster.

Answer (score -4):

### Bro Use this!

- I have comment my css So you can get What I have added.
- add css in your code and see changes if anything let me know

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/sunset_horizon_above_clouds_4k-1366x768.jpg");
  /*---I have added this CSS Try it--*/
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  /*--------*/
}
button{
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:28px;
    -webkit-border-radius:28px;
    border-radius:28px;
    border:1px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:16px 31px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
button:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://www.google.lv/"><button>Ej uz Google!</button></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS is fine — https://jsbin.com/pehizaxofe/1/edit?html,js,output — the problem must be with the URL or the web server configuration.

Comment: actually when I loaded your code it only show me button then I fixed the background if problem is ongoing just link css file correctly or add css file to same folder

Comment: I just tested the link in my previous comment in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and it worked fine in all three. What are you testing with where it fails?

Comment: No Bro Now its fine I say when i first copy and paste your code then it shows me only button but now everything looking cool... ;)

Comment: Why are you copy/pasting my code when I linked to a live demo? Do you mean Nauris Francuzēvičs' code? I am not Nauris Francuzēvičs. The live demo I made used their code except I replaced the `<link>` with `<style>`. That code works in the live demo without copy/pasting anywhere.

Comment: yes Bro I have seen this link https://jsbin.com/pehizaxofe/1/edit?html,js,output.
if everything is fine from your side then kindly accept my answer its very greatful to me if any problem just let me know I resolve it.

Comment: I can't accept your answer. (a) As I pointed out in my last comment: **I didn't ask the question** and (b) As the link I posted in my initial comment and you just copy/pasted shows: The CSS in the question works **without your modifications** (therefore this can't be the correct answer).

Comment: okay No problem but see my modified css and compare this with your css you see the change

Comment: I can see the change. The change doesn't solve the problem. And **it is not my CSS**

Comment: Okay but you ask me everything is fine